# T-SQL stored procedure - select just a few columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a stored procedure which selects all the columns from the table. But I need to select only few of them.

How do I assign a variable to select few columns from a table?

Existing stored procedure code:

```
DECLARE @DatabaseName NVARCHAR(255) = N’AdventureWorksDW’
DECLARE @SchemaName NVARCHAR(255) = N’dbo’
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(255) = N’DimProduct’

BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

-- Declare the parameters internal to query
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX) = N”
DECLARE @ParamDefinition NVARCHAR(MAX) = N”
DECLARE @ColumnList TABLE (
ColumnId INT IDENTITY(1,1)
, ColumnName NVARCHAR(255)
, ColumnMaxLength INT
, ColumnMinLength INT
)

DECLARE @ColumnMaxLength INT
DECLARE @ColumnMinLength INT
DECLARE @ColumnCount INT = 0
DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = 1
DECLARE @ColumnName NVARCHAR(255)

SET @SQLString =
N’SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ‘
@DatabaseName + N’.’ + N’INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
DATA_TYPE IN (”CHAR”, ”NCHAR”, ”VARCHAR”, ”NVARCHAR”)
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @SchemaName
AND TABLE_NAME = @TableName’

SET @ParamDefinition = N’@SchemaName NVARCHAR(255), @TableName NVARCHAR(255)’

INSERT INTO @ColumnList (ColumnName)

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParamDefinition, @SchemaName, @TableName
SELECT @ColumnCount = COUNT(*) FROM @ColumnList

WHILE (@LoopCounter <= @ColumnCount)

BEGIN

SELECT @ColumnName = ColumnName
FROM @ColumnList
WHERE ColumnId = @LoopCounter

SET @SQLString =
N’SELECT ‘
‘@ColumnMinLength = MIN(LEN(‘ + @ColumnName + ‘))’
‘, @ColumnMaxLength = MAX(LEN(‘ + @ColumnName + ‘))’
‘ FROM ‘
@DatabaseName + N’.’ + @SchemaName + N’.’ + @TableName
‘ WITH (NOLOCK) ‘

SET @ParamDefinition = N’@ColumnMinLength INT OUTPUT, @ColumnMaxLength INT OUTPUT’

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParamDefinition, @ColumnMinLength OUTPUT, @ColumnMaxLength OUTPUT

UPDATE @ColumnList

SET
ColumnMinLength = @ColumnMinLength
, ColumnMaxLength = @ColumnMaxLength
WHERE ColumnId = @LoopCounter

SET @LoopCounter += 1

END

SELECT
ColumnName AS [Column Name]
, ColumnMinLength AS [Column Minimum Length]
, ColumnMaxLength AS [Column Maximum Length]
FROM @ColumnList
ORDER BY [Column Name]

END
```

Comment: Variables don't select columns. If you need to change the columns in your procedure then you need to modify the procedure.

Comment: What have you tried?  Perhaps if you showed a bit of the procedure, this would be easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can [build dynamic SQL query](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/build-sql-server-dynamic-sql-query-example.aspx) and execute it as follows

```
create procedure SELECT_MyTable (
    @fieldList nvarchar(max)
)
as
declare @select nvarchar(max)

set @select = 'SELECT ' + @fieldList + ' FROM MyTable'

exec sp_executesql @select

GO

declare @fieldList nvarchar(max) = 'UserName,region'
exec SELECT_MyTable @fieldList
```

Comment: Be prepared to hear all about SQL Injection attacks when you don't use parameterized queries, in 3... 2... 1...  And yes, I realize you can't use parameters for column names.  Just be sure that @fieldList is generated internally and not from any user input and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you select from the table directly instead of using a stored procedure?

If so, you can use the syntax

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, ColumnN
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Below is the script I am working on